# Calling object methods polymorphically

Tags: scala, types

```
class A 

class B extends A

object B {
  def createSidekick = new B
}

class C extends A

object C {
  def createSidekick = new C
}

object foo {
  def bar[T <: C] = {
    // T.createSidekick
  }
}
```

In foo.bar, I would like to call methods from the given object. However, Scala does not allow to extend objects, so there is no obvious way of accomplishing this. What is the best way to accomplish this sort of behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
class A

class B extends A

trait Sidekicker[T <: A] {
  def createSidekick: T
}

object B extends Sidekicker[B] {
  def createSidekick = new B
}

class C extends A

object C extends Sidekicker[C] {
  def createSidekick = new C
}

object foo {
  def bar(s: Sidekicker[_]) = s.createSidekick

  val b = bar(B)
  val c = bar(C)
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there might be some elegant solution where I just use the Type parameter

Comment: Do you mean bar[B] instead of bar(B)? Well, that's just a matter of personal taste whether you like more rounded shapes or sharp ones.

Comment: @user1225310: You could use type classes like this: [link to pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/rkbLHwRs). Note that you could define `implicit val` for `Sidekicker[T]` not only in companion object.

Comment: @RadoBuransky: you could add typeclasses implementation as alternative option to your answer.

Comment: @senia: Interesting, thanks. When would you recommend "mine" and where  "your" approach?

Comment: @RadoBuransky: See [this article](http://seanparsons.github.io/scalawat/Typeclasses.html) for addition information about typeclasses.